# Where can I ask about XLIFF?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I've just recently started to implement support for [XLIFF 2.0](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/xliff-core/v2.0/xliff-core-v2.0.html) in a software product.

> XLIFF (XML Localisation Interchange File Format) is an XML-based format created to standardize the way localizable data are passed between tools during a localization process and a common format for CAT tool files.
>   – [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLIFF)

My questions (and perhaps answers) will be of technical nature focused on implementing (programming for) XLIFF.

#### Question example

> What is the driving motivation for an *Extractor* tool to generate multiple `<segment>` elements in a `<unit>` as opposed to generate multiple `<unit>` elements with just a single `<segment>`?
>
> Is there a general recommendation available for how an *Extractor* should generate segments?

**Which StackExchange site is the best match for this?**

---

This question is not a duplicate of "*[Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/255624)*" because:

- I'm asking for expertise in the XLIFF 2.0 standard.
- I believe that a similar question could be asked about LaTeX in [TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com) or perhaps in [English](http://english.stackexchange.com).
- The example question is not based on opinion. An expert in XLIFF could probably explain:

  - Why one way is better than the other; or
  - Why one way is actually illegal; and/or
  - Why both options exist in the standard and how they are different.
- [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) is not a good fit.
- If there were a site for *Computer Aided Translation* or *Translators* then that would probably be a good fit.

Comment: Can you give an example question?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: I've just added one.

Comment: asking for recommendations/opinions is off-topic on all sites pretty much. Even were there to be a site for XLIFF it would likely not accept such a question.

Comment: @RobertLongson: The example question I posted isn't asking for someone's opinion or recommendation. I'm trying to ask about *best practice* or *standardized recommendation* for how to generate XLIFF content in order to maximize its usefulness for the XLIFF toolchain (translators in particular).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Comment: @gnat: I don't see how.

Comment: difference explanation [added in rev 4](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/279290/revisions) looks quite solid (retracted duplicate vote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Software implementation questions are supposed to be asked on Stack Overflow if they are accompanied with some code (usually the latter is true, although there are exceptions).

There are no sites dedicated to translators or builders of such software.

Your question though might get closed since it read like to 'point me to an off-site resource' question, which is off-topic on any site in the network.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try Stack Overflow then. I don't understand why the question is read like *point me to an off-site resource*. Could you elaborate a little bit so that I might understand what's wrong?

Comment: @MårtenWikström "Is there a general recommendation available". Answer: "Yes, you can find it here [link]"

Comment: Ah! I see now (pretty obvious :-)). Do you think that the question would be better if I didn't include that part and just had the "What is the driving motivation for X as opposed to Y?" part instead?

Comment: Yes, although that might be 'opinion based'. In some sites/tags they don't like this kind of open ended questions.